# SQL Server Management Studio compatible with Windows 10 32 bit

Tags: ssms, windows-10

I'm running a VM with Windows 10 32 bit OS and I need to install SQL Server Management Studio.

The OS on my VM

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.19044 N/A Build 19044
```

The install for the last version fails with an error, the log shows that it fails installing the x64 redistributables

the site for the download shows that the compatible OS are

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

```
Windows 11 (64-bit)
Windows 10 (64-bit) version 1607 (10.0.14393) or later
Windows 8.1 (64-bit)
Windows Server 2022 (64-bit)
Windows Server 2019 (64-bit)
Windows Server 2016 (64-bit)
Windows Server 2012 R2 (64-bit)
Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)
Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)
```

I'm struggling to find what is the latest version of SSMS compatible with Windows 10 32 bit version

Comment: "*I'm running a VM with Windows 10 32 bit OS*" - Why 32-bit? You won't be able to use SSMS.

Comment: SSMS is new requirement. I use this VM for remote desktop connections through a VPN, and the miniumum RAM requirement for 32 bit Windows is 1 GB instead of 2 GB for the 64 bits Windows 10.

Comment: 1 GB, even 2 GB, of RAM is not enough to **realistically** run Windows. You should be using 64-bit, 32-bit is basically deprecated at this point, and modern apps like SSMS don't support it.